# Where are Javascript functions like Number(), parseInt(), String() defined?

Tags: javascript

I have checked name of properties defined in window global object, but I am not able to see any property matching above names(String, parseInt etc). Below is the JS code I used to find properties:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var prop in window){
            document.write(prop + '\n');
        }
    </script>
```

Edit:
Based on below comment I did a console log and it prints: **ƒ String() { [native** code] }.

This raises another question. When I define a function in my script, I can find a property with same name as this function name, by using code. So what is special in these casting functions(Number(), String()) that I cant see them when I enumerate using for-in.

Are these casting functions written in a different syntax, which somehow is not enumerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for...in` only iterates over **enumerable** properties. The ones you want to find may not be enumerable. Just do

```js
console.log(window.String);
```

However, a bit more about where they are defined:

They are define in the global environment. An environment is basically a map that associates *names* with *values*, also called *bindings* (a value is bound to a name). For example giving the following code:

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = "abc";
```

the environment created when this code is evaluated would look something like

```
+-------------+
| foo |  42   |
|-----|-------|
| bar | "abc" |
+-------------+
```

JavaScript has two basic types of environments: **declarative** environments and **object** environments.

**Declarative** environments cannot be accessed directly, e.g. there is no value you can reference to iterate over all its entries. An example for a declarative environment is a function environment, i.e. the environment that is created when a function is called. There is no way to iterate over all the variables declared inside a function.

An **object** environment on the other hand is an environment that is "backed" by an ordinary object. That means that the bindings are not stored somehow internally but are actually properties of that object.

The global environment is such an environment, it is (partially) backed by the global object, which in browsers is `window`. That's why built-in global bindings are also properties of the global object.

You can find a list of all built-in global bindings [in the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-global-object).

Having said that, the global object is not necessary for the global environment to work/exist or for the built-in global variables to exist. Those are all simply created when the global environment is created (because the specification says so). You can also access those values without going through the global object:

```js
console.log(String);
```

---

> So what is special in these casting functions(Number(), String()) that I cant see them when I enumerate using for-in.

[The specification simply says that these built-in global values should not be enumerable:](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects)

> Every other data property described in clauses 18 through 26 and in Annex B.2 has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }` unless otherwise specified.

---

> Are these casting functions written in a different syntax, which somehow is not enumerable?

Well, most of these functions are implemented in native code (e.g. C++), they are not implemented in JavaScript. However, that's not what makes them non-enumerable. Every property has a bunch of flags associate with them one of them being the `enumerable` flag. When you normally create properties you are not bothered with these flags and they just have some default value.

But you can create non-enumerable properties easily, e.g. with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {value: 42, enumerable: false});
console.log(obj.foo);
for (var prop in obj) console.log(prop);
```

Comment: "*You can also access those values without going through the global object*" Isn't the following example accessing the global object anyway?

Comment: Indirectly, yes, since `String` is a built-in global. But consider `const foo = 42;`. `const` declarations are not backed by the global object. My point is rather that a global object is not required for JavaScript to work, the language could also have been defined to use only a declarative environment for the global environment. But maybe this hypothetical case is more confusing than helping :-/

Comment: On testing the last snippet of code, despite having enumerable:true, I am not able to print 'foo' in console.

Comment: @Mohit: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/hv0j79uc/ . I had a typo in the example, make sure you didn't have the same (by default `enumerable` is `false` when using `Object.defineProperty`)